# Radio button text area

Tags: php, html

I have this survey form which works perfectly fine. I just need this one question to be changed. Basically there's 2 radio buttons for Answers "Yes" and "No" and a text area under them. Now I want the text area to be locked unless the user selects the "Yes" radio button then they can type in the text area a reason for "Yes".

I did some looking around and attempting this function but it doesn't seem to be working.

```html
<script>
  function validate() {
    var radioYes = document.getElementById('radioYes');
    var textarea = document.getElementById('question5comment');

    if (radioYes.checked && question5comment.value.length < 1) {
      alert('Please enter your reason for Question 5.');
      question5comment.focus();
      return false;
    }
  }

  function toggle(value) {
    document.getElementById('question5comment').disabled = value;
  }
</script>

5. Are you using other non-franchise service centres? 
<br>
*if yes is there any other reason you would do so other than price
<br>
<input type="radio" name="question5"
       value="Yes" required>Yes
<br>
<input type="radio" name="question5"
       <value="No" required>No 
<br>
<textarea name="question5comment"  rows="5" cols="40" required></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong:

1. Unnecessary `<` before `value`.
2. No `id`s that are referring in your code.
3. Syntax errors.

Use the following:

```js
function validate() {
  var radioYes = document.getElementById('radioYes');
  var textarea = document.getElementById('question5comment');

  if (radioYes.checked && question5comment.value.length < 1) {
    alert('Please enter your reason for Question 5.');
    question5comment.focus();
    document.getElementById('question5comment').disabled = true;
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('question5comment').disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
5. Are you using other non-franchise service centres?
<br>*if yes is there any other reason you would do so other than price
<br>
<input type="radio" name="question5" value="Yes" required onclick="validate();" id="radioYes" />Yes
<br>
<input type="radio" name="question5" value="No" required onclick="validate();" id="radioNo" />No
<br>
<textarea name="question5comment" id="question5comment" rows="5" cols="40" required></textarea>
```

Comment: that worked just had to change the true and false around. but i would like the alert to only pop up if they try and submit without typing anything in the text area. is that possible sir?

Comment: Yes, in your submit handler, check the value's length and then if it is yes.

Comment: perfect sir im all set. only last thing is can i make the textarea locked by default? so when the form opens the text area is locked

Comment: @EternalJ Just add `textarea.disabled = true;` at the starting. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You have many missing code ! Like id not exist , function is created but no initialise called its.

```
<script>
function validate(t) {
var question5comment = document.getElementById('question5comment');    
if (t.checked && question5comment.value.length < 1) {
    alert('Please enter your reason for Question 5.');
    question5comment.focus();
    return false;
}
toggle(t.value);
}

function toggle(value) {
    document.getElementById('question5comment').disabled = (value == "Yes") ? false : true;
}
</script>


5. Are you using other non-franchise service centres? 
<br>
*if yes is there any other reason you would do so other than price
<br>
<input type="radio" name="question5"
value="Yes" onchange="validate(this)" required>Yes
<br>
<input type="radio" name="question5" onchange="validate(this)" value="No" required>No 
<br>
<textarea name="question5comment" id="question5comment" rows="5" cols="40" required></textarea>
```